# Converting char[][] to char[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, char

My goal is to print a new string like

```
char[] result = someArray();
System.out.print(new string(result))
```

I am working with 2 dimentional array in my task `char[][]`.

I would like to convert my `char[][]` array to `char[]`

How do I either print a single string directly from `char[][]` or easily convert it to `char[]`?

`Arrays.toDeepString()` does not work for me as it prints in the format `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]` and I am looking for an output that is `abcdef`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

- the [`stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) streams the 1D arrays.
- the [`String::valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char%5B%5D)) maps each of those arrays to a String
- the [`joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--) joins the string with an empty delimiter.

```java
char[][] chs = {{'a','b'},{'c','d','e'}};
String str = Arrays.stream(chs)
      .map(String::valueOf)
      .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(str);
```

Prints

```
abcde
```

If you want to print each array separately, you can do the following:

```java
for (char[] ch : chs) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ch));
}
```

Prints

```
[a, b]
[c, d, e]
```

Answer (score 2):

2D arrays of chars can be easily converted into single string using [`String(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char%5B%5D)) constructor for each "row" array of chars followed by joining the resulting strings:

```java
static String singleString(char[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
                 .map(String::new)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

"Streamless" version using [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) may look as follows:

```java
static String singleString(char[][] arr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
            arr.length * (arr.length > 0 ? arr[0].length : 0));
    for (char[] row : arr) {
        sb.append(new String(row));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate all array and concat rows / columns according to the logic you want to implement.

Say you have the following:

```
[[a] [a] [a]]
[[b] [b] [b]]
[[c] [c] [c]]
```

iterate the first row, and create a new char array with "aaa", second one - "bbb", third one - "ccc".

```
[aaa][bbb][ccc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```java
char[][] matrix_char = {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd', 'e'}};
String result = Arrays.deepToString(matrix_char).replaceAll("[\\[ ,\\]]", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

Or the straightforward:

```java
char[][] matrix_char = {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd', 'e'}};
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (char[] row : matrix_char)
    for (char col : row)
        result.append(col);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
abcde
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all of these characters into a single string and then convert this string to a 1d character array. This method works with character code points, so it can also handle *unprintable characters*:

```java
char[][] arr2d = {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d'}, {'e', 10, 0}};

char[] arr = Arrays.stream(arr2d)
        // concatenate each subarray into one string
        .map(String::new)
        // join all strings into a single string
        .collect(Collectors.joining())
        // convert this string to a character array
        .toCharArray();

// output
for (char ch : arr) {
    // integer codepoint and unicode name of the character
    System.out.println(0 + ch + " - " + Character.getName(ch));
}
```

Output:

```css
97 - LATIN SMALL LETTER A
98 - LATIN SMALL LETTER B
99 - LATIN SMALL LETTER C
100 - LATIN SMALL LETTER D
101 - LATIN SMALL LETTER E
10 - LINE FEED (LF)
0 - NULL
```

---

<sup>See also: [Why do I get a number when I add chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66429041/15309136)</sup>