# Why do I get a number when I add chars?

Tags: java, char, type-conversion, integer

I once decided to add two chars together, and it gave me a number. Here's the code:

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println('a'+'b');
  }
}
```

Output: `195`.

I've searched in a lot of places, but I still couldn't figure out why a `char + char = int`. Can someone explain this to me?

**NOTE:** THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE!! The other question is asking the data type of an added char. This question asks why this happens. Those are DIFFERENT QUESTIONS WITH DIFFERENT ANSWERS!

Comment: Here's a decent read on the subject: http://www.vias.org/javacourse/chap07_09.html

Comment: You can check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8688708/9462470

Comment: A simplified way to think about is that `char` variables contain a number value which represents it's position in the ASCII table. Arithmetic operations using `char` have various behaviors depending on how it's used because a `char` contains a number value but represents an character so the system will perform automatic conversions depending on the context of its use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding their ASCII values:

```
'a'+'b' = 97+98 = 195
```

Answer (score 1):

[5.1. Kinds of Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1)

This code implicitly casts them to `String`:

```java
System.out.println("" + 'a' + 'b'); //ab
```

And this code casts to `double`:

```java
System.out.println(.8 + 'a' + 'b'); //195.8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatanate, try this :

```
System.out.println("a"+"b");
```