# Convert an ASCII numeric value into a character

Tags: java, android, character, ascii, inputstream

I want to send numeric data from the terminal app as a ASCII with Bluetooth to the Android app, and inside the Android app, to convert  ASCII numeric data to characters.

I only found one solution, but it reads as a single byte.
I wrote this command for Android app to get data:

```java
InputStream stream;
if (stream.available() > 0) {
    int a = stream.read();
    int x = Character.getNumericValue(a);
    this.mmOutStream.write(x);
    this.mmOutStream.flush();
}
```

This command

```java
int a = stream.read (); /// 128
```

It takes the data as a ASCII and throws it inside a

This command

```java
int x = Character.getNumericValue(a); /// 1 2 8
```

ASCII converts to characters, but gives a single byte of data.
That is, I give the number as a ASCII, for example, the number 128
128 to converts to 1 2 8.
But I want 128, but he gives it to me one by one.

Comment: I didn't understood what you want to achieve.....

Answer (score 1):

You can cast an ASCII decimal value to `char` as follows:

```java
int ch = 125;
System.out.println((char) ch); // }
System.out.println(Character.getName(ch)); // RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
```

---

<sup>See also: [Why do I get a number when I add chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66429041/15495739)</sup>