# Check that string contains a character from array

Tags: java, string, java-stream, character, contains

I would like to check that string that is a filename contains a illegal argument from the `ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS`. Simply I could use for loop, but I want to do this by *Streams*.

My code:

```java
package shared;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Validator {
    private static final Character[] ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS =
            {'/','\n','\r','\t','\0','\f','`','?','*','\\','<','>','|','\"',':'};

    public static boolean fileNameIsValid(String fileName) {
        return Arrays.stream(ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS).anyMatch(fileName::contains);
    }
}
```

Problem is in contains method cuz It needs a `CharSequence` instead of `char`. Is there any way to do this by stream without changing `Character[]` type to `String[]`?

Comment: *"I want to do this by Streams"* In my opinion, you should be wanting to do this using regex.

Comment: .. another way to deal with the presence check of a `Character` in a `String` is to get the `indexOf` that character.

Comment: Why don't you just turn the characters into strings? I.e. `String[] ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS = { "/", "\n", "\r", ... };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Streams might not the best fit here. Also, now your solution has quadratic complexity (N*M, where N is the file name length, and M is the size of your illegal character array), which is not very performant. As proposed in the comments, you could use a regular expression:

```java
private static final Pattern ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_REGEX =
        Pattern.compile("[/\n\r\t\0\f`?*\\\\<>|\":]");

public static boolean fileNameIsValidRegex(String fileName) {
    return !ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_REGEX.matcher(fileName).find();
}
```

Or, if your illegal character set is limited to ASCII, you could play around with a bitset to squeeze some performance:

```java
private static final BitSet ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS = new BitSet();

static {
    for (char c : new char[]{
            '/','\n','\r','\t','\0','\f','`','?','*','\\','<','>','|','\"',':'}) {
        ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS.set(c);
    }
}

public static boolean fileNameIsValid(String fileName) {
    return fileName.chars().noneMatch(ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS::get);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)):

```java
return Arrays.stream(ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS)
             .map(fileName::indexOf)
             .anyMatch(i -> i >= 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I would recommend that you use a `Set` instead of an array, because you don't have any need for indexing your stuff, then Stream over the characters from the given string, and check if there is any match with your set.

Get the chars from the `chars()` method on a string, this will give you a array of integeres, which you then can cast to an char "array"

Here's all you need:

```java
private static final Set<Character> ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS = Set.of(
        '/','\n','\r','\t','\0','\f','`','?','*','\\','<','>','|','\"',':');

public static boolean fileNameIsValid(String fileName) {
    return fileName.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .noneMatch(ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS::contains);
}
```

Comment: you don't need to `mapToObj` if your `ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS` are integers.

Comment: Yes, you could directly create a list of ints for the illegal chars

Answer (score 0):

If [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method *needs a `CharSequence` instead of `char`*, then you can *give it to it*:

```java
Arrays.stream(ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .anyMatch(fileName::contains);
```

But under the hood in the `String` class, this method uses [`indexOf(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) method:

```java
public boolean contains(CharSequence s) {
    return indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;
}
```

So, to avoid redundant type conversion, you can use another [`indexOf(int ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) method:

```java
Arrays.stream(ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS).anyMatch(ch -> fileName.indexOf(ch) > -1);
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to “subtract” 2 given strings In Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66530947/15402945)</sup>